# Select records between 3 different work shifts?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a data table called "Requests" that records the requests made by employees in a company, I used to use a Stored Procedure to get all the request from a single workday (starting at 6am and ending at 6am of the next day)

```
USE [DataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_GetRequests]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_GetRequests]
as begin
DECLARE @from datetime 
set @from = getdate();
if (DATEPART(HOUR, @from) < 6) set @from = dateadd(day, -1, @from);

DECLARE @start_date datetime = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(9), @from, 112) + '06:00');
DECLARE @end_date datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @start_date)

select * FROM Requests
where RequestDate between  @start_date and @end_date
end
```

Now I need another stored procedure to get all the request from a specific work shift.

The company has 3 work shifts (1st: 6am to 2pm / 2nd: 2pm to 10pm / 3rd: 10pm to 6am).

Is there a way to get all the requests from a single shift?

For example: if the current time is 5am, to only show the requests from the 3rd shift (10pm to 6am) and if it is 3pm to only show the requests from the 2nd shift (2pm to 10pm)

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefixed is *reserved* by Microsoft and means "Special Procedure". Use of it should be avoided, as if Microsoft ever create a Special Procedure with the name of your Stored Procedure, yours will cease to work. Also, using the `sp_` prefix comes with a performance hit. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick script to get you started.

```
Use AdventureWorks2017;
Go
If OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Requests') is not null Drop Table #Requests
Create Table #Requests (id int identity (1,1) primary key, [Name] varchar (1), DateTime1 Datetime)
Insert into #Requests ([Name], DateTime1)
Select 'A', '2020-04-03 07:00' UNION ALL
Select 'B', '2020-04-03 15:00' UNION ALL
Select 'C', '2020-04-03 23:00'


Declare @timeofinterest datetime
--Set @timeofinterest = GetDate()
Set @timeofinterest = '2020-04-03 12:00'
--Set @timeofinterest = '2020-04-03 18:00'
--Set @timeofinterest = '2020-04-03 02:00'

If cast(@timeofinterest as time) between '06:00' and '14:00'
Begin
Select *
from #Requests
where cast(DateTime1 as time) between '06:00' and '14:00'
and cast(Datetime1 as date) = cast(@timeofinterest as date)
End
If cast(@timeofinterest as time) between '14:00' and '22:00'
Begin
Select *
From #Requests
where cast(DateTime1 as time) between '14:00' and '22:00'
and cast(Datetime1 as date) = cast(@timeofinterest as date)
End

If cast(@timeofinterest as time) between '22:00' and '23:59' or cast(@timeofinterest as time) between '00:01' and '06:00'
Begin
Select *
From #Requests
where cast(DateTime1 as time) between '22:00' and '23:59' or cast(DateTime1 as time) between '00:01' and '06:00'
and cast(Datetime1 as date) = cast(@timeofinterest as date)
End
```

The functionality around midnight needs a bit of work but this uses an if … else to return the records in question. If the time is in shift x it will only return records from that shift.

Hope this helps.